# How to center div horizontally with width bigger than 100%?

Tags: html, css

I have divs inside divs. I want to center the content horizontally and I've tried a couple of solutions that work, but when I set the width of the content to 150%, the content goes to the right or the width keeps at 100%. This was one of my tries, along with changing the width to another div and the css to another div as well. I can't find all the CSS those classes use because it's written in more than one document, but I don't think they are the issue because we're overwritting the pre-existing css. Does anyone have any solution?

```html
<section class="content">
      <div class="row" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; ">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="justify-content: center;width: 150%;">
          <div class="card card-primary">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h3 class="card-title">Detalhes</h3>

              <div class="card-tools">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" title="Collapse">
                  <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form id="registarProduto">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Descrição</label>
                  <input type="text" id="descrProd" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Valor de Compra</label>
                  <input type="text" id="vCompraProd" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Valor de Venda</label>
                  <input type="text" id="vVendaProd" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Quantidade</label>
                  <input type="text" id="stockProd" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Alertar para quando a quantidade for menor que:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="stockMinProd" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Observações</label>
                  <textarea id="obsProd" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
              </form>
              <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-12">    
                  <button type="button" onclick="registarProduto()" class="btn btn-success float-right">Registar</button>
                </div>  
              </div>
              
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.card -->
        </div>
  </div>
  
  
    
  </section>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using bootstrap, so I suggest using their classes, and try to keep your own css to a minimum. You can use row `<div class="row justify-content-center">` for instance.

Comment: @ChrisLear It worked! I didn't want to change much in the classes because I've had errors for it, but this was an easy solution that solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: Good to hear it. In general, bootstrap seems to work very well indeed, as long as you stick to their guidelines. Adding your own css code will generally just generate more and more problems. So my advice (for what it's worth) is to always look at the bootstrap documentation for solutions before writing custom css

Comment: Ok thank you! Can't I mark your answer as correct?